# using count in a subquery and getting errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i have line by line data in a table and i need to net of cancellations from sales and produce a report grouping on a scheme identifier. i.e i need to find all the sales and  subtract all the cancellatsion to prduce a net sales figure.

i am trying to use the query below but i'm getting errors.

`select insscheme, ((select count(quote_id) where (sale = '1')) - (select count(quote_id) where cancellation = '1')) as sales from policys
group by insscheme
order by insscheme`

and i'm getting the error

`Column 'policys.Sale' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Your sub queries don't say what table they are from. I'm assuming policys [sic].

Comment: yes, they are all coming from the same table.

Comment: What datatype are `sale` and `cancellation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any sub queries here. Just use `COUNT` and `CASE`.

```
SELECT   insscheme,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN sale = '1' AND cancellation <> '1' THEN 1 END) AS sales
FROM     policys
GROUP BY insscheme
ORDER BY insscheme
```

I have assumed above that `cancellation` is not nullable. If it is use

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN sale = '1' THEN 1 END) -  
COUNT(CASE WHEN cancellation = '1' THEN 1 END) AS sales
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work.

```
select  insscheme, SUM(sale) - SUM(cancellation) as NetSales
from    policys
group by insscheme
```

I don't see what the quote_id column has to do with your query.  Are you querying one table or several?  It would help if you could show us what your schema looks like with a brief discussion of your table layout.

Comment: sale and cancellation are actually an nvarchar filed due to import issues, although it may be possible for me to change this to a nueric so i can sum them . many thanks for your help.